# Update file via php

Tags: php

The form with the input element is below:

```
<?php
$post_new_file=$_FILES['post_new_file'];
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
if (!empty($post_new_file)) {                

  $post_file=$_FILES['post_new_file']['name'];
  $post_file_temp=$_FILES['post_new_file']['tmp_name'];
  move_uploaded_file($post_file_temp,"../pdf/$post_file");                     
                     }
$query="UPDATE posts SET post_file='{$post_file}' WHERE post_id='{$the_post_id}' ";
$create_post_query=  mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 confirmQuery($create_post_query);

?>
<form action="edit.php?source=<?php echo $the_post_id ?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group" style="border: solid #000 3px;">
   <label for="post_file">Select New File</label>
    <input type="file" name="post_new_file" >
    </div>
  </form>
```

I have problem when the $post_new_file exist. In this case when updating I lost the data in my db and the post can't have access into the file. In a few words I don't want changing the access of the file when I haven't insert a new file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should check if `$_FILES['post_new_file']['tmp_name']` is empty, the  _FILES['post_new_file'] will exist even if there was an error with the file upload. you may even want to check the move upload worked as well to be extra sure you actually have the file, as the file could be uploaded but if the move fails you will lose the file as it was only stored temporarily

Comment: It is empty and I have the file.

Comment: @liontass i dont know what that comment means.